# Accessing a UIView from its UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

simple question
how do I access something in my `UIView` from the `UIViewController`? 
i tried

```
self.view.functionname(variables)
```

but it dosent work..

Comment: What do you want to access `function` or `variable`?

Comment: Its not clear at all what you're trying to accomplish here. If you're trying to access a UIView from the VC's view, you need to have a pointer to it somewhere in code.

Comment: i was trying to access a func in my UIView from the viewcontroller . the solution was  -      (self.view as! MyView'sName).myFunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was -

```
 (self.view as! MyView'sName).myFunction
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the view of viewController
yourViewController.view